# Is there a way to normalize / zero point SVG path data?

Tags: apache-flex, svg

I have a path that can plot it self anywhere on the page. So I will have a path that is in the middle of the container. The path data is something like:

```
M 100 100 L 100 200 L 200 200 L 200 100 z
```

That creates a box at the coordinates x 100, y 100. But I want to normalize it or zero point it so that the coordinates will end up:

```
M 0 0 L 0 100 L 100 100 L 100 0 z
```

And then I set the x to 100 and y to 100. In this example, I can do simple math because the path is a square but if it's not, for example, if it's a line going from right to left or a complex path, is there code that will zero point it?

Please ask for clarification if needed instead of downvoting.

Here is the source code of the [Path](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flex-sdk/repo?p=flex-sdk.git;a=blob;f=frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/primitives/Path.as;h=370d2e45315e33ded7e3d3720b284de15d1e1ba4;hb=ea8a5ab637cb4cb46f240433cb8f44cfd34dfd1a) class in Flex which uses AS3 (like JavaScript) looks like it has functions that may help get the bounds using the [Path](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/Path.html) class.

FYI To inform readers of my tag selection Flex and FXG is the markup language that is a sibling of SVG (both created by Adobe). The path data is the same for both languages and the markup are almost 1 to 1. An answer that works in one may work in another. Also, the DOMParser can parse SVG and I can use that if it will help.

Comment: use relative co-ordinates such as l instead of L

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simple math, regardless of the complexity of your path. Just iterate over the points and identify the minimum x and y values. Et voilà! That is your "zero point" offset. You have already unconsciously applied the same algorithm to your square, where it's obvious.